# How can I sort and do pagination on a filtered foreign key count?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a foreign key from `Entry` to `Vote` and I want to sort on `Vote` that are created before a certain date. How can I go about doing that in a nice fashion? Normally I would do:

```
entries = Entry.objects.annotate(
    num_votes = Count('votes')).order_by('-num_votes')

page = request.GET.get('page')
paginator = Paginator(entries, 12)
try:
    entries = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    entries = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    entries = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

How can it be sorted so that it only counts votes created before a certain date? Is my only alternative to query the DB and iterate over everything?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply add on the filter, it should include that filter within the aggregate. You would use the related_name of the foreign key in order to filter that part of the join.

```
entries = Entry.objects.annotate(
    num_votes = Count('votes')).order_by('-num_votes')

entries = entries.filter(votes__created__lte=some_date)
```